# Shinyapps.io : packages are not loaded

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I wrote a Shiny App with R Shiny, I created an account on Shinyapps.io and every step worked with `rsconnect`, and  `rsconnect::deployApp('/path/to/my/app')` open a new window where my app is supposed to be displayed.

The problem is that shinyapps cannot load the packages I used in my code.
The error message is :

**An error has occurred**

The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

*Le chargement a nécessité le package : readxl*

*Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :*

*aucun package nommé ‘readxl’ n'est trouvé*

(I just put the warning for one package but there's the same for every one of them)

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake : I had called all of my packages like `library("readxl")` instead of `library(readxl)` (without quotation marks) in both app.R (where I write the shiny app) and data.R (where I do all my data stuff)

I removed the quotation marks and it works now